# Сретенье - что означает слово?

Tags: значение-слов, этимология

Недавно мы отметили православный праздник Сретенья Господня, после которого началась масленичная неделя.
Скажите, пожалуйста, а что вообще означает слово "сретенье"? Как я понимаю, это из старославянского, да? А то праздник-то, понятно, знаю, а значение слова - нет.

Comment: Так кто же с кем встретился, в честь какой встречи праздник? http://tradicii.com/sretenie-gospodne.html Это очень интересно.
Кстати Масленица - праздник народный, родом из язычества,то есть из другого ряда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"ВСТРЕТИТЬ" исконно русское слово. Префиксное производное от стретить, восходящего к "съретити" со вставным "т" (ср. с такими же "т" диал. "страм"). Сретить «встретить» восходит к реть «встреча» (с «ять»), в др.-рус. яз. ещё известного. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Согласно евангельскому повествованию, на сороковой день после Рождества Христова и по исполнении дней законного очищения Пречистая Богородица вместе со святым Иосифом пришла из Вифлеема в Иерусалим ко храму Божию, принеся сорокадневного младенца Христа. По закону Моисееву, родители должны были приносить в храм для посвящения Богу своих первенцев (то есть первых сыновей) на сороковой день после рождения. При этом полагалось в благодарность Богу принести жертву. Во исполнение этого закона Матерь Божия с Иосифом и принесли младенца Иисуса в храм Иерусалимский, а для жертвы принесли двух птенцов голубиных.
Сретение — это встреча человечества в лице старца Симеона с Богом. Симеон Богоприимец был человек праведный и благочестивый. — по преданию, один из семидесяти двух учёных толковников-переводчиков, которым египетский царь Птолемей II Филадельф (285—247 до н. э.) поручил перевести Священное Писание с еврейского на греческий язык. Когда святой Симеон переводил книгу пророка Исайи и прочитал слова «Се Дева во чреве приимет и родит Сына», он подумал, что это явная описка и вместо «Дева» должно стоять «Жена», и посчитал своим долгом исправить текст. Но ангел Господень остановил руку святого Симеона и уверил его, что он не умрёт, пока не убедится в истинности пророчества пророка Исайи.
Симеон долго ждал исполнения обещания Божия — он жил, по преданию, около 300 лет. И вот в этот день по внушению Духа Святого он пришёл в храм. И когда Мария с Иосифом принесли Младенца Иисуса, Симеон взял Его на руки и, славя Бога, сказал:
« Ныне отпускаешь раба Твоего, Владыко, по слову Твоему, с миром, ибо видели очи мои спасение Твое, которое Ты уготовал пред лицем всех народов, свет к просвещению язычников и славу народа Твоего Израиля.(Лк. 2:29—32)

Comment: Надо же! Не знала. Спасибо огромное!!

Answer (score 2):

Вот я сделал скриншоты из "Полного церковно-славянского словаря" Гр. Дьяченко . стр.655 , 656 / инт.ссылка [ПЦСС](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0655.htm) / :                                            [image: Стр.655]  [image: Стр.656]